# DBCC TABLE CHECK seems to hang

Tags: sql-server, dbcc, dbcc-checkdb

Our nightly maintenance plan includes a database integrity check which normally takes 45 minutes to complete. Now it appears to hang. When looking at the Activity Monitor, a series of process items are listed with the same session id. They are largely all the same, here is a summary

Task State: SUSPENDED
Wait Time: All the same and now more than one day
Wait Type: CXPACKET
Wait Resource: exchangeEvent id=Port3fcfae200 WaitType=e_waitPortOpen nodeId=0

This is the second day, we rebooted the server but it happened again as soon as we ran the check.

For context, we are running SQL Server 2012 BI Edition, 8 cores, 14 GB of memory. Overall CPU is around 18%. This is being run as the SQLServerAgent. The only recent change in the server was the configuration of some push publishing (transactional replication)

Comment: `CXPACKET` wait type just means it's running in parallel and waiting on some other thread(s). Is any of the threads waiting on something else (some other wait type)? Also, instead of Activity Monitor, try using [sp_WhoIsActive](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2012/03/22/released-who-is-active-v11-11.aspx).